# access case class parameter actor

Tags: scala, actor

I have a specific question that I am unsure where to put or how to find the answer. I am learning about actors in scala and I have a case class that contains the actor, which I need to reply to, in its parameters. How do I access that? It would look like this:

```scala
class ActorPlayAround() extends Actor {
   def receive = {
      case GetUpdate => //I want to reply to the actor with an update
   }
}

object ActorPlayAround {
   case class GetUpdate(replyTo: ActorRef)
}
```

I thought I would solve it like this:

```scala
case GetUpdate => (replyTo which I can't access) ! Update()
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. This is only a simplified code snippet that I hope shows my struggle.

Comment: `case GetUpdate(replyTo) => replyTo ! Update()` See https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html

Comment: I knew I just forgot something simple! Thanks!

Comment: Looks good! Perhaps add as an answer rather than a comment?